# C# function returns different types. How do I declare return value? Evaluate return value?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing a VSTO, new to C# and having a problem declaring and evaluating the return value. This function returns an Excel.Range or bool. I want to do nothing if it is bool and doSomething() if it is a Excel.Range.

```
[SomeType] range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox(Prompt: Prompt,Title: Title, Type: 8);

if ([SomeConditionStatement]) {
    doSomething(); }
```

Comment: what research did you do on how to check if an object is of a given type, and what problems did you have applying what you found to your situation?

Comment: is, GetType(), typeof but they all fail with an exception if I get the other type than I am checking for

Comment: `if(range is Excel.Range)`? Probably your `InputBox` returns `object`?

Comment: @bravogolfgolf Then show the code that you're using, and explain specifically what problems you're having when you use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `InputBox` is `object`. You can accommodate that with a `var`, and then match its actual type with the [`is` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx).

```
var range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox(Prompt: Prompt, Title: Title, Type: 8);

if (range is Excel.Range)
{
    doSomething(); 
}
```

Note that according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx), `InputBox` would not return anything but a `Range`, when the Type parameter is 8:

> If Type is 8, InputBox returns a Range object.

Comment: What I observed is that an InputBox of Type 8 has two buttons: OK and Cancel. If a range is entered then OK returns the range. If OK is clicked without a range it displays an error. If Cancel is clicked then it returns false.

Comment: This function is once documented on [MSDN-office dev center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx), and a second time in [MSDN interop docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox.aspx). The office dev one is much better than the one I previously linked, it even explains that Cancel always results in `false`, just like you observed > updated the link

Answer (score 0):

I find it a bit more convenient to use `as expectedType` instead and check for `null`:

```
Range range = Application.InputBox(Prompt, Title, Type: 8) as Range;

if (range != null)
{
    object[,] values = range.Value2 as object[,]; 
}
```

Other examples:

```
var s = range.Text as string; 

var c = range.Cells[1] as Range;

var w = Application.Worksheets["Sheet1"] as Worksheet;

var d = Application.Evaluate("COUNTA(A1:A9)") as double? ?? -1;
```